# What are some problems in which bayesians and frequentists get different results?

Tags: probability-theory, big-list, bayesian

The [German tank problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem) is one such (found through [this question)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1223096/how-can-bayesian-and-frequentist-approach-be-different), which is an example from estimation theory.

Other than in the case of estimation, what are some problems in which the two schools will come to different conclusions?

Of course, [this xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1132/) has to be mentioned.

Comment: I wish I could +2 for the xkcd cartoon alone!